# How to get dynamic buttons value when button is click in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have created dynamic buttons in php. I need to get the value of that button when particular button is click. And when we click the button, all information is fetch in to the form.

Here is my code for buttonclick

```
<?php

function dash()
{
    include 'config.php';
    $sql = "SELECT  roomno FROM roombook";

    if($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql))
    {
            $str = '';

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                // generate array from comma delimited list
                $rooms = explode(',', $row['roomno']);

                //create the dynamic button and set the value
                foreach ( $rooms as $k=>$v )
                {
                    $str .= '<input type="button"  onClick="showDiv()" name="btn_'.$k.'" value="'.$v.'" id="btn_'.$k.'"/>';
                }
            }

            return $str;
        }
        else {
            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($db);
            }

    mysqli_close($db);
}   
?>

<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>room boking</title>

  <link href="css/bootstrap1.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/front.css">

</head>
<body>
<form method="post"  action="">
<div class ="  row box col-md-4" >
<div style="color:black"><?php echo dash();?></div>
</div>

</form>
```

Here fetching the value in form code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
include 'config.php';
    if(isset($_POST['book']))
    {
    $roomno=$_POST['roomno'];
    $roomtype=$_POST['roomtype'];
    $location=$_POST['location'];
    $charges=$_POST['charges'];
    $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
    $address=$_POST['address'];
    $city=$_POST['city'];
    $state=$_POST['state'];
    $pincode=$_POST['pincode'];
    $mobilenumber=$_POST['mobilenumber'];
    $idtype=$_POST['idtype'];
    $idnumber=$_POST['idnumber'];
    $Adate=$_POST['Adate'];
    $Ldate=$_POST['Ldate'];
    //echo  $roomno."<br>".$roomtype."<br>".$location."<br>".$charges."<br>".$firstname."<br>".$lastname."<br>";
    if(strlen($firstname)<3)
    {
        echo "<script>alert('First name is to short')</script>";


    }
    else if(strlen($lastname)<3)
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Last name is to short')</script>";


    }
    else if(strlen($address)<3)
    {
        echo "<script>alert('UserName name is to short')</script>";


    }
    else
    {
        $query=" INSERT INTO customerbook(roomno,roomtype,location,charges,firstname,lastname,address,city,state,pincode,mobilenumber,idtype,idnumber,Adate,Ldate) VALUES('$roomno','$roomtype','$location','$charges','$firstname','$lastname','$address','$city','$state','$pincode','$mobilenumber','$idtype','$idnumber','$Adate','$Ldate')";
    //$query="INSERT INTO customerbook(roomno,roomtype,location,charges,firstname,lastname,address,state,city,pincode,mobilenumber,idtype,idnumber,Adate,Ldate) VALUES('$roomno','$roomtype','$location','$charges','$firstname','$lastname','$address','$state,','$city','$pincode','$mobilenumber','$idtype','$idnumber','$Adate','$Ldate')";
    if(mysqli_query($db, $query))
    {
        echo "<script>alert('booking  seccessfully')</script>";
        //header("Location:login.php"); 
        }
    else echo "error";
    }
}

$sql = "SELECT  roomno,roomtype,location,charges FROM roombook where roomno='101'";

if($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){    
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                   $roomno=$row['roomno'];
                   $roomtype=$row['roomtype'];
                   $location=$row['location'];
                   $charges=$row['charges'];

        }

        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($db);

?>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>booking Form</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap1.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/book.css" rel="stylesheet">

</style>
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="js/book1.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="head" id="link">
<div class="panel panel-primary" style="margin:20px;">
    <div class="panel-heading">
            <center><h3 class="panel-title">booking Form</h3></center>
    </div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <form method="post" action="">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12 ">
            <label for="roomno">Room Number*    </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="roomno" value='<?php echo $roomno; ?>'  placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="type">Room Type*</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="roomtype" value='<?php echo $roomtype; ?>' placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="location">Location*</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="location" placeholder="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="charges">charges*</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="charges" placeholder="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="customer name">First Name*</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="firstname" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="customer name">Last Name*</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="lastname" placeholder="">
        </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <label for="address">Address*</label>
          <textarea class="form-control input-sm" name="address" rows="3"></textarea>
       </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="city">City*</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="city" placeholder="">
        </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="state">State*</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="state" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="pincode">Pincode</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="pincode" placeholder="">
        </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="mobile">Mobile Number*</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="mobilenumber" placeholder="">
        </div>
    <div class = "form-group col-md-12">
          <label for="years">Id Type *</label>   


          <select class="form-control input-sm" name="idtype">
        <option>-- Select Id Card --</option>
        <option>Pancard</option>
        <option>Adhar Card</option>
        <option>voting card</option>


          </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="idnumber">Id Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="idnumber" placeholder="">
        </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="arrival">Arrival Date</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm datepicker" name="Adate" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="arrival">Leaving  Date</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm datepicker" name="Ldate" placeholder="">
        </div>
</div>


<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12 " >
            <center><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" name="book"/><center>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **WARNING:** When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. DO NOT use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, as it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: save your value in data-attribute and then fetch using it

Comment: please explain in details

Comment: Dont pass messages to the front, just pass a json & deal with it on the frontend. & for the love of God and all that is sacred, bind values instead of interpolating them into an insert query.

Comment: i have posted it as a answer

Answer (score 0):

You can create your button like this

```
$str .= '<input type="button"  onClick="showDiv()" data-atribute-id="valueyouwant" name="btn_'.$k.'" value="'.$v.'" id="btn_'.$k.'"/>';
```

Script should be like

```
$("button").click(function() {
    alert(this.id); OR
    alert($(this).attr('id')); OR
    alert($(this).attr('data')); OR
    var btnid = $(this).attr('data');//which give you current clicked btn id
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
// is going to select all elements that its name start with *btn_* (your dynamic buttons)

$('[name^="btn_"]').click(function() {
    //get the value of the button that was clicked
    var buttonValue = $(this).val();

    // send data to the other file using the action attribute of the form
    $('form').submit();
});
```

Hope that can help.